# parseFloat not working with zero after decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point, numbers, precision

I have a text box , form the text box I need to pass a **float** value to a api.

Now things are working fine when I have value inside the text box as "18.575" or "18.09483".

But in case the value is "18.000" things are not working. I understand that 18.000 is same as 18 but I need the precision digits.

So problem is **I need exact 18.00 in JavaScript and not 18**

I tried

a) **parseFloat**

```
  parseFloat("18.000");  // I get 18
```

b) **toFixed**

```
 (18).toFixed(2) // I get `"18.00"` but it is string and doesn't solve the purpose.
```

c) **Number**

Number("18.00") // gives 18 and not 18.00

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: When using in expression, use the Number and when showing to the user use String.

Comment: The number `18.000` is exactly the same as the number `18`. In other words, the internal representation of those two are bit-for-bit identical. Binary floating point representation does not make it possible to retain precision information. You'll have to find a fixed-point library.

Comment: @Tushar , I tried number but it is also not working

Comment: The 18.00 can only exist as a string. As a number or float it's 18.

Comment: @Pointy I understand that , but I need digits with precision for current requirement between other language support this things :(

Comment: Yes @Ma3x , I am too of this view still looking for any solution if it exists

Comment: Then you'll have to use strings, not numbers, and parsing to number makes little sense

Comment: How do you pass the data to the API? Json?

Comment: @adeneo , if I don't get a way I will tell other developer to change the flow

Comment: @georg I am passing data in  JSON

Comment: This is quite easy, the number `18` can't be represented as `18.00` in javascript, no matter how you parse it, it's impossible, it has to be a string to be represented that way. Why not rewrite the API so it works with whole numbers, that's what it should do

Comment: thanks for your view @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native JSON doesn't provide a way to specify floats precision, you can hack around this by manipulating encoded json string, like

```js
    data = {
        something: 18
    };
    
    json = JSON.stringify(data, function(key, val) {
        if(typeof(val) === 'number')
            return '<<<' + val.toFixed(3) + '>>>';
        return val;
    }).replace(/"<<<|>>>"/g, '');

    document.write(json)
```

which is kinda silly, but works

Comment: What is the point of adding and then removing the delimiters? Can't the callback just return the (string) result of `.toFixed()`?

Comment: @Pointy: the question is not very clear, but I guess that their backend (probably written in php) requires floats to always contain a decimal point. Therefore neither `"foo":"18.00"` nor `"foo":18` will work.

Comment: Right, but `.toFixed()` already returns a string, not a number.

Comment: Without delimiters, I'll get `"foo":"18.00"` while I need `"foo":18.00` in my json.

Comment: But ... when you do it *with* the delimiters, you'll end up with `"18.00"` in the JSON anyway. If not, there's no point, since we're back to the problem of number representation.

Comment: @Pointy: sorry, I'm not getting that. The OP wanted (if I read the question correctly) a json string like `{"foo":18.00}` (=decimal point, no quotes) and this is what my code does. If I simply return `toFixed` from the callback, I'll get `{"foo":"18.00"}` (=string), which is not what they're looking for.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing. Well the OP isn't super-clear, so you may be right. However, as soon as `18.00` is parsed by almost any programming language, it'll turn into a normal double-precision value and once again be indistinguishable from `18`. However, you're right that it's possible that the root problem is some horrible API that expects JSON with zeros after decimals or something.

Comment: If this is a working solution for OP, the API that accepts this JSON has to be fixed to properly accept numbers (`{"foo":18}`) or strings (`{"foo":"18.00"}`). Using workarounds like this will only resurface the same problem when some other code will call the same API.

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
parseFloat((18).toFixed(2))
```

Comment: @shankaranand it is not working, it is converting to string